# excel table row column lookup

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm struggling with some Excel functions.

I have a table with row header and column header and then data. For example:
If I have a type of pizza, crossed with its Size, and the data is the price.

```
               S    M      L    XL
 Cheese        6    6.5    8    10
 Pepperoni     6.5  7.5    10   12
 Supreme       8    9      12   15
```

If I have this table in excel, how can I do a lookup of the price if I know I want "Cheese", "M"?

The row and colmn headers will be text and not necessarily be in any type of sorted order.

thanks!!

Comment: how about this tutorial? http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/13780/using-vlookup-in-excel/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Index match:

```
=INDEX(A:E,MATCH("Cheese",A:A,0),MATCH("M",1:1,0))
```

To call with data in cells so it is dynamic:

Say in F1 you have `Cheese` and in G1 you have `M`:

```
=INDEX(A:E,MATCH(F1,A:A,0),MATCH(G1,1:1,0))
```

[image]

The first part of the Index formula is the Search range.  In this case full column A to E.

The second part denotes what row.  The match finds the first instance of "Cheese" in column A and returns that row.

The third part denotes the column.  That match finds "M" in Row 1 and returns the column number.

Now Index, using those coordinates, knows what to return.

Comment: This is mostly working, thanks! The part I'm having trouble with. is if I replace "Cheese" with a cell reference that contains the string "Cheese" it no longer finds a match.. I've mad sure there are no strange fonts/formatting issues. none that I can see anyway

Comment: @WithoutMeItJustAweso Does the string have the quotes around it?  It should not.  See edits

Comment: @WithoutMeItJustAweso maybe there are extra spaces in some of the cells?  I added a picture to show it working.  There has to be unprintable characters in the cells for this not to work.

Comment: Looks like I still had some sneaky unprintable characters, got it working. out of curiosity, is there a way to do a 'contains' instead of a straight match so things like trailing spaces wouldn't matter?

Comment: @WithoutMeItJustAweso Yes you can wrap each lookup value like this `"*" & F1 &"*"` But you want to be careful because it will now find the first that has that string in it.  For example if you had `Pepperoni & Sausage` before `Pepperoni` it would grab the first.  It is always better to do exact lookups whenever possible.

Answer (score 2):

Adjust your range references as necessary ($A$2:$E$4 contains the table data, $A$1:$E$1 is your headers - sizes in this case).  You can also replace the "Cheese" and "M" with cell references.

```
=VLOOKUP("Cheese",$A$2:$E$4,Match("M",$A$1:$E$1,0),FALSE)
```